# Is function object returned by std::mem_fn required to have a const overload

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, libc++

When I run this code with libc++:

```
struct foo
{
    foo(int x) : x(x)
    {}
    int x;
};

int main()
{
    const auto select_x = std::mem_fn(&foo::x);
    foo f(1);
    printf("%i\n", select_x(f));
}
```

I get an error like this:

```
mem_fn.cpp:16:20: error: no matching function for call to object of type
      'const std::__1::__mem_fn<int foo::*>'
    printf("%i\n", select_x(f));
                   ^~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/functional:1224:11: note: 
      candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const
      std::__1::__mem_fn<int foo::*>', but method is not marked const
          operator() (_ArgTypes&&... __args)
          ^
```

It seems that libc++ is missing a `const` overload. It work using libstdc++. Is this a bug in libc++? Or does the standard require a `const` overload?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see the standard specifying anything about the const-callability of the wrapper returned by `mem_fn`. From [func.memfn] (quoting N4140):

> ```
> template<class R, class T> unspecified mem_fn(R T::* pm);
> ```
>
> 1 *Returns*: A simple call wrapper (20.9.1) `fn` such that the
>   expression `fn(t, a2, ..., aN)` is equivalent to `INVOKE (pm, t, a2, ..., aN)` 
>   (20.9.2). `fn` shall have a nested type `result_type` that
>   is a synonym for the return type of `pm` when `pm` is a pointer to
>   member function.
>
> 2 The simple call wrapper shall define two nested types named
>   argument_type and result_type as synonyms for `cv T*` and `Ret`,
>   respectively, when pm is a pointer to member function with
>   cv-qualifier `cv` and taking no arguments, where `Ret` is `pm`’s
>   return type.
>
> 3 The simple call wrapper shall define three nested types
>   named  `first_argument_type`, `second_argument_type`, and
>   `result_type` as synonyms for `cv T*`, `T1`, and `Ret`, respectively,
>   when `pm` is a pointer to member function with cv-qualifier `cv` and
>   taking one argument of type `T1`, where `Ret` is `pm`’s return type.
>
> 4 *Throws*: Nothing.

The reference to [func.def] (though *simple call wrapper* is actually defined in [func.require]) is equally unilluminating. This pretty much only guarantees that whatever it returns is usable directly.

As a quality of implementation issue, though, I see no reason why the wrapper shouldn't be const-callable, and it looks like this actually has been fixed [over a year ago](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/functional?r1=191626&r2=199848). You might want to try updating your XCode to see if you can pick up a more recent version of the library.